# Bash Scripting: How to open Kate with directory and filename?

Tags: bash, launching-application

I am completely new to Bash scripting so bare with me while I try to describe this.
What I want to do be able to insert two arguments.
Arg1=Sub Folder in Documents
Arg2=Title of the text file

Using Ubuntu 20.10. (If that matters)
In short: **kate ~/Documents/$Arg1/$Arg2** would be the equivalent to the command I would enter into my terminal.

The extra catch is having a keyword shortcut for the Sub Folder. For example say the Sub folder was name SUPERLONGNAME_EXTRALONG but I want a shortcut such as SHORTNAME=SUPERLONGNAME_EXTRALONG

```
#!/bin/sh

newfile()

    dirname=$1
    filename=$2

    if $dirname==dir1
        dirname=newdirname
        fi

kate ~/Documents/$dirname/$filename
```

This is basically what I have now. Although as you would guess this doesn't work. (Provided for aid in seeing what I am trying to do). I can open kate within the home directory with the file name of my choice. My real issue seems to be the creating a shortcut keyword. As well as having the file save to the **Document/Arg1** directory. Please help.

I run the command through terminal using
`sh newfile arg1 arg2`

Comment: Test it, `if test "$dirname" = dir1; then dirname=newdirname; fi`

Comment: Or use the `case` statement which also POSIX sh compatilbe afaik, `case $dirname in  dir1) dirname=newdirname;; esac`

Comment: Also https://shellcheck.net to validate your shell script.

Comment: I wrote you a script below, but I would like to point out that modern shells have file completion so typing: `kate ~/Do<tab>/Lo<tab>/newfile.txt` is probably is easier to remember and shorter to type.  This also means you don't have sync the shortnames array with your file system.

Comment: @Jetchisel For some reason this fixed the problem of accessing the Documents folder although does not allow me still to go to the sub folder within the Documents directory.

Comment: @AllanWind thank you for the script as well as this comment. This is mainly for my learning. Trying to get used to creating bash scripts.  I am aware of file completion. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an associate array shortnames to optionally translate from long to short names.  Verify that file and directory exist:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A shortnames=( 
  [long]="short"
)

d=$1
f=$2
if [ -z "$d" ]
then
    echo directory required
    exit 1
fi
if [ -n "${shortnames[$d]}" ]
then
    d=${shortnames[$d]}
fi
d=~/Documents/$d
if [ ! -d "$d" ]
then
     echo "directory $d does not exist"
     exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$f" ]
then
    echo file required
    exit 1
fi

kate "$d/$f"
```